# which is way to store 12,000 or above rows locally in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to store two fields city id and city name and isFavourite locally in android.currently I stored data in SQLite but this is time consuming. So I read other so there is defined shared preference but I don't know is this proper way? I also heard about internal storage and external storage In this fetching data process is faster or not?

**Some code that I used for store data:**

```
 public void saveCity(String table,int cityid,String cityName,int isfavourite) {
    database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(COLUMN_CITYID, cityid);
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_CITYNAME, cityName);
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_isFavourite, isfavourite);

    database.insert(table, null, contentValues);

    database.close();
}
```

I create bus booking application so in this I gave search city option for this purpose I want to stored city persistent

Comment: Sqlite is definitely preferable to sharedpreferences for this task. If you find it slow, modify your question giving full information.

Comment: thanks for replay.....which type info you want??

Comment: What is the way you are using your data? Do you need join, select, sort it, random access? How often do need to access it? How critical is speed for you?

Comment: you can begin by showing what your table looks and and also showing what queries you find to be slow.

Comment: Reopening the database for every single city certainly will be slow.

Comment: CL thanks...reopening is also issue in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Fast Inserting data in your database Use `PrepareStatement` for it, and for more fast execution make `ArrayList` for your Data and call method only one for insert all data into the database

```
public void saveCity(String table, ArrayList<CustomCityClass> cityList) {


        String sql = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO " + table + " ( "+COLUMN_CITYID +","+ COLUMN_CITYNAME +","+ COLUMN_isFavourite+") VALUES ( ?, ?, ?)";

        mDatabase.beginTransactionNonExclusive();
        SQLiteStatement stmt = mDatabase.compileStatement(sql);

        for (int x = 0; x < cityList.size(); x++) {
            stmt.bindLong(1, cityList.get(x).getCityID());
            stmt.bindString(2, cityList.get(x).getCityname());
            stmt.bindLong(3, cityList.get(x).getisFavourite());

            stmt.execute();
            stmt.clearBindings();

    }
        mDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();
        mDatabase.endTransaction();


    }

}
```

and make Custom `POJO` class `CustomCityClass` for your city data

Comment: i have arraylist of my data how i used it in your code

Comment: @Varshilshah always wc. Happy Coding

Comment: abhishek you use bindLong but i stored int value why?

Comment: in SQLiteStatement there are no method for bindInt

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of storage available to Android applications.

1. Shared Preferences
2. Sqlite

**1.Shared Preferences:**

It is a light weight storage. We can store key value pairs in this storage.

Ex. Email, Password.

**2. Sqlite**

It is used to store some heavy datas. It will store data in table(rows and columns).

You have mentioned you want to store 12,000 data with city id and city name, so you have to use sqlite to store your data.

Comment: If you want to improve the speed of storing the data in sqlite then use transaction.  db.beginTransaction();
try {
    saveCities();
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch {
    //Error in between database transaction 
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}

Answer (score 0):

best way to store and retrive data from local storage is [Realm](https://realm.io/news/realm-for-android/)

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to try Realm which is free ORM available.
also it is too easy and much faster thn Sqlite!!

look out here [Realm Java](https://realm.io/products/java/).