# how to insert in sqlite checking if entry exits and if exists update it and if not present then insert

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

This is my create function which inserts array data in database.Data is fetching from server and inserting in db.

```
public long createEmployee_New(ArrayList<Customer> aCustomer) {

        long row_id = 0;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        for(int i = 0;i<aCustomer.size();i++) {

            Customer employee = new Customer();
            employee = aCustomer.get(i);
            values.put(EMP_ID, employee.getEmpID());
            values.put(EMP_TYPE, employee.getEmpType());
            values.put(EMP_CITY, employee.getEmpCity());
            values.put(EMP_NAME, employee.getEmpName());
            values.put(EMP_CONTACT_PERSON, employee.getEmpContactPersonName());
            values.put(EMP_CONTACT, employee.getEmpContactNo());
            values.put(EMP_ADD, employee.getEmpAddress());
            values.put(EMP_STATE, employee.getEmpState());
            values.put(EMP_DELSTATE, employee.getEmpDelState());
            values.put(CUSTOMER_LANDLINE, employee.getCustomer_landline());
            values.put(CUST_COMPANY_ID, employee.getCust_companyID());
            values.put(CUSTOMER_EMAIL_ID,employee.getCust_emailID());
            values.put(PRICE_LIST_ID_FK,employee.getPRICE_LIST_ID_FK());

            row_id = db.insert(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, null, values);
        }

        db.close();
        return row_id;
    }
```

how can i check if empid which is unique exits in table if exists then update the data for that particular empid and if its not present in db then create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Updating and Inserting data you can also Use below method

```
mDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, null, values,
                SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
```

Comment: always wlc @PrachiKarapurkar

Comment: i have 5000 + plus employee . what is the best way to insert them in db?

Comment: @PrachiKarapurkar please show here my answer for same as your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37699920/which-is-way-to-store-12-000-or-above-rows-locally-in-android/37700670#37700670

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method [`insertWithOnConflict`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertWithOnConflict(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int)) with `CONFLICT_REPLACE` constant like,

```
db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Cursor cursor = null;
 String idValue="5"; //the employee id which you want to insert 
 String sql ="SELECT EMP_ID FROM "+TableName+" WHERE EMP_ID="+ idValue; 
 cursor= db.rawQuery(sql,null);
 Log("Cursor Count : " + cursor.getCount());

 if(cursor.getCount()>0){
  // employee ID Found put update query here
 }else{
 //employee ID Not Found  put insert query here
 }
```

Comment: what will be idValue ?? i m passing arraylist

Comment: the employee id which you want to insert

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace into 
command instead of insert into command.
It works on mysql.

Comment: i have 5000 + plus employee . what is the best way to insert them in db?

Comment: mysql have bulk insert syntax that can insert 5000 records with one insert command. I doubt other DBMS can do it. But in other DBMS you can commit your changes after inserting thousand records for speed up the operation.

Comment: can u send some link which can help me out with the issue

Comment: for the above code create employee in which i m passing arrylist contaions 5000+ employees . How can i insert them smoothly without cell being hanged

Comment: I don't have good information about mobile programming. But I think you must do bulk insert in another thread to avoid hanging in GUI.

Comment: yes m doing same bt it crashes after some time and half data is placed in db

Comment: I don't have any idea why it crashes. But I think it is related to android.